# AngularJS runs function twice althought the controller is being initiated only once

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been googling for a while but just can't seem to find the reason why my function is being executed twice. I've dumbed the code down to a few lines and still can't figure it out. I've done literally the same on another application but I don't remember having the same problem. Maybe you guys can help me out.

```js
angular.module('indexApp', []).controller('indexController', function ($scope) {
    console.log("init");
    $scope.somefunc = function (pEpochTime) {
        alert("Why does this execute twice?");
        return "asdf";
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<section ng-app="indexApp" ng-controller="indexController as indexCtrl">
    <div class="container">
        <div>{{somefunc('asdf')}}</div>
    </div>
</section>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kcuqhf99/6/

Comment: Maybe because when using ng-controller="indexController as indexCtrl" syntax, you should not define the controller like .controller, but it should be defined as a normal function.

Comment: The controller isn't being initiated twice? The console.log() runs only once.

Comment: use indexCtrl.somefunc('asdf') in your view. see whether that makes the issue solved

Comment: Isn't working at all. Tried that already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you bind expression with the function, not with variable, Angular will  execute the expression with each $digest loop.

Added maurycy comment:
*Digest runs twice, first time by variable watcher and second time to check if the first run changed another variable, so you get minimum 2 digest runs and maximum 10 by default*

Check this out https://jsfiddle.net/1k2bg82v/1/

```
angular.module('indexApp', []).controller('indexController', function ($scope) {
    console.log("init");
    $scope.somefunc = function (pEpochTime) {
        alert("Why does this execute twice?");
        return "asdf";
    };

    $scope.do = function(){
        console.log('doing');
    };
});
```

I added ng-click event that has nothing with your expression, but as ng-click starts digest loop, it fires your function once again.

Read more about $watch here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

> If you want to be notified whenever $digest is called, you can
>   register a watchExpression function with no listener. (Be prepared for
>   multiple calls to your watchExpression because it will execute
>   multiple times in a single $digest cycle if a change is detected.)

Comment: I suppose that makes sense, although I don't understand the reasoning behind that. How would one get rid of that problem, though? Thank you very much for your help, Misha.

Comment: A little explanation on the 2 digests. It's not like you said with rootScope and controller scope. Digest runs twice, first time by variable watcher and second time to check if the first run changed another variable, so you get minimum 2 digest runs and maximum 10 by default

Comment: @MarianneMarkwardt Instead to bind a function, bind a variable and it will run once https://jsfiddle.net/1k2bg82v/7/ .

Comment: @maurycy You are correct, I tried adding one more controller and it still run twice. Tnx, I'll update the answer.

Comment: I came up with that myself but thought that was kinda counter intuitive. It seems more like a hack to me and not like an actual solution. Thanks a lot, Misha.

Comment: @MarianneMarkwardt no problemo. To me it looks logical to use variables to represent application state. Functions should be there to change the state. When function is binded, Angular cannot know if something has changed unless it execute the function. When variable is binded, Angular can check if something changed and activate watchExpression only if changed.

Comment: somefunc is a function which expects a parameter, though. Maybe I just don't grasp the concept. I don't know.